# installing pip in google cloud server failed

Tags: python, linux, pip, putty, apt-get

I created a linux virtual machine in google cloud server and copied all the files from my raspberry pi that I used earlier.

I'd like to install the modules and libraries I used in my scripts but when I run the `sudo apt-get install python-pip` command in putty (after logging into the google cloud) I get the following error:

```
Err:1 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates/main amd64 linux-libc-dev amd64 4.9.30-2+deb9u3
  404  Not Found [IP: 21x.2xx.xx2.x2 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/pool/updates/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_4.9.30-2+deb9u3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 21x.2xx.xx2.x2 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

How could I fix this problem?

Thanks

Comment: what was the outcome of the update and fix-missing?